# javascript returns NaN in additition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to calculate total number of links click by user. To do so i am using following code

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function fnc()
    {
    document.getElementById("atext").innerHTML="tested";
    var iStronglyAgreeCount=parseInt (document.getElementById("ISA") );
    document.getElementById("ISA").innerHTML=iStronglyAgreeCount +1;
    }
       </script>
    </head>
  <body>
 <a href="#">  <label id="atext" onClick="fnc()">I strongly   agree</label></a> (<span><label id="ISA">0</label></span>) 

</body>
```

I am storing starting number 0 into a variable and trying to add 1 at each click.But it shows NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the `text` content of the element.

```js
function fnc() {
  document.getElementById("atext").innerHTML = "tested";
  var iStronglyAgreeCount = parseInt(document.getElementById("ISA").textContent);
  document.getElementById("ISA").innerHTML = iStronglyAgreeCount + 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <label id="atext" onClick="fnc()">I strongly agree</label>
</a>(<span><label id="ISA">0</label></span>)
```

**Note:** If target browser is `<IE9`, consider using [*Polyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Polyfill_for_IE8)

Comment: thank you it works for me. I will accept in 11 minute !